# I am trying to Practice React Routing but I can't get it to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

This is my super simple App.js file:

```
import About from "./Pages/About";
import Contact from "./Pages/Contact";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is the index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);


reportWebVitals();
```

The problem comes when I try to view this in the browser and I get the following message:

"Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem."

I've tried following exactly what people do in online tutorials but my code just doesn't work. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Here are my Components:

```
const About = () => {
  return (
    <div className="about">
      <h1>This is the About Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;
```

AND:

```
const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <div className="contact">
      <h1>This is the Contact Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Comment: Move your broswerRouter inside app.js not index.js

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Because when I try to do so, it is working for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-joliot-e61pe?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I see no issue with your router and routes. I suspect the issue is in one of the routed components, either `About` or `Contact`, or both. Can you update your question to include all relevant code? Can you also confirm what versions of React and React-Router-Dom you are using? From your project directory run `npm list react react-dom react-router-dom`.

Comment: I've added my Components, maybe that will be of some help to identify the problem :)

Comment: "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.2"

Comment: Other than missing a `"/"` path I don't see any issue in your code. Have you made sure to kill any watchers/hot reloaders and restart your local dev server? IF issue is persisting then can you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?